# Typescript same enum format but different enums as prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have a component that takes in an enum as a prop.

The enums for the sake of argument look like this

```
export enum val1 {
    val11 = "val1"
    val12 = "val2"
    val13 = "val3"
    val14 = "val4"
    val15 = "val5"
}
```

and

```
export enum val2 {
    val21 = "val1"
    val22 = "val2"
    val23 = "val3"
    val24 = "val4"
    val25 = "val5"
}
```

I have a component which goes

```
interface componentProps {
    valueEnums: val1 | val2
}
```

instead of defining the prop as val1 or val2, is there a more scalable way to abstract the entire thing so only one type has to be defined since the format is pretty much the same?

I want to use the values in the enums and map them through Object.keys()

Comment: You mean like `type BothEnums = val1 | val2;`?

Comment: If the two enums have the same values then... just remove one of them and use the other one everywhere?  I'm guessing that's not an option but I'm not seeing why; could you elaborate on why you need two identical-valued enums to exist?